# What is the best performance metric used in balancing dataset using SMOTE technique

Tags: python, class-imbalance, performance, smote

I used smote technique to oversample my dataset and now I have a balanced dataset. The problem I faced is that the performance metrics; precision, recall, f1 measure, accuracy in the imbalanced dataset are better performed than with balanced dataset.

Which measurement can I use to show that balancing dataset may improve performance of the model?

NB: roc_auc_score is better in balanced datset than roc_auc_score with imbalanced dataset
Can it be considered as a good performance measurement?
after the explanation i implemented code and i got this results

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split,StratifiedShuffleSplit,cross_val_score
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import interp
from time import *
from sklearn import metrics
X=dataCAD.iloc[:,0:71]
y= dataCAD['Cardio1']
# Split the dataset in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
print(y_test.value_counts())
model=SVC(C=0.001, kernel="rbf",gamma=0.01, probability=True)
t0 = time()
clf = model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
t = time() - t0
print("=" * 52)
print("time cost: {}".format(t))
print()
print("confusion matrix\n", metrics.confusion_matrix( y_test, y_pred))
cf=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
accuracy=(cf.item((0,0))/50)+(cf.item((1,1))/14)
print("model accuracy \n",accuracy/2)
print()
print("\t\tprecision_score: {}".format(metrics.precision_score( y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\trecall_score: {}".format(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\tf1_score: {}".format(metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\troc_auc_score: {}".format(metrics.roc_auc_score( y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
```

Results:

```
Name: Cardio1, dtype: int64
====================================================
time cost: 0.012008905410766602

confusion matrix
 [[50  0]
 [14  0]]
model accuracy 
 0.5

        precision_score: 0.390625

        recall_score: 0.5

        f1_score: 0.43859649122807015

        roc_auc_score: 0.5
```

For balanced dataset

```
X_train1,y_train1 = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train.ravel())
df= pd.DataFrame({'Cardio1': y_train1})
df.groupby('Cardio1').Cardio1.count().plot.bar(ylim=0)
plt.show()
print(X_train1.shape)
print(y_train1.shape)
#model=SVC(C=0.001, kernel="rbf",gamma=0.01, probability=True)
model=SVC(C=10, kernel="sigmoid",gamma=0.001, probability=True)
t0 = time()
clf = model.fit(X_train1,y_train1)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
t = time() - t0
print("=" * 52)
print("time cost: {}".format(t))
print()
print("confusion matrix\n", metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
cf=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
accuracy=(cf.item((0,0))/50)+(cf.item((1,1))/14)
print("model accuracy \n",accuracy/2)
print()
#print("\t\taccuracy: {}".format(metrics.accuracy_score( y_test, y_pred)))
print()
print("\t\tprecision_score: {}".format(metrics.precision_score( y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\trecall_score: {}".format(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\tf1_score: {}".format(metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print()
print("\t\troc_auc_score: {}".format(metrics.roc_auc_score( y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
```

Results:

```
(246, 71)
(246,)
====================================================
time cost: 0.05353999137878418

confusion matrix
 [[ 0 50]
 [ 0 14]]
model accuracy 
 0.5


        precision_score: 0.109375

        recall_score: 0.5

        f1_score: 0.1794871794871795

        roc_auc_score: 0.5
```

I found  no efficient results. Should i implement the model using cross validation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, just to be clear, you **shouldn't** evaluate the performance of your models on the balanced data set. What you should do is to split your dataset into a train and a test set with ideally the same degree of imbalance. The evaluation should be performed **exclusively** on the test set, while the balancing on the training set.

As for your question, any **macro averaged metric** should do just fine for proving that your balancing technique is effective. To calculate such a metric (let's say accuracy for simplicity), you just need to compute the accuracies of each class **individually** and then **average** them.

**Example**:
We trained two models `m1` and `m2`, the first without balancing the dataset and the second after using SMOTE to balance the dataset.

Actual values :  `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1`
Predicted `m1`: `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`  <-- only predicts majority class
Predicted `m2`: `1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1`

How would we normally calculate accuracy?

$acc = \frac{correct \, predictions}{total \, predictions}$

How do our two models perform on this metric?

$acc_1 = \frac{8}{10} = 80\%$
$acc_2 = \frac{7}{10} = 70\%$

According to this performance metric, `m2` is better than `m1`. However, this isn't necessarily the case as `m1` just predicts the majority class! In order to show how `m2` is better than `m1`, we need a metric that treats the two clases as equals.

We' ll now try to calculate a macro-averaged accuracy. How? First we'll calculate the accuracy for each class separately, and then we'll average them:

- For `m1`:
  $acc_1^0 = \frac{8}{8} = 100\%$ <-- `m1`'s accuracy on class `0`
  $acc_1^1 = \frac{0}{2} = 0\%$  <-- `m1`'s accuracy on class `1`
  $macro\_acc_1 = \frac{acc_1^0 + acc_1^1}{2} = \frac{100\% + 0\%}{2} = 50\%$
- For `m2`:
  $acc_2^0 = \frac{5}{8} = 62.5\%$ <-- `m2`'s accuracy on class `0`
  $acc_2^1 = \frac{2}{2} = 100\%$  <-- `m2`'s accuracy on class `1`
  $macro\_acc_2 = \frac{acc_2^0 + acc_2^1}{2} = \frac{62.5\% + 100\%}{2} = 81.25\%$

**Notes**:

- Macro averaging can be applied to any metric you want, however it is most common in confusion matrix metrics (e.g precision, recall, f1).
- You don't need to implement this by yourself, many libraries already have it (e.g. sklearn's [f1_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) has a parameter called `average`, which can be set to `"macro"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great explanation it's clear concise Could you propose some scientific articles to real??

Comment: A few articles on the matter: [1](http://www.ijcst.com/icaccbie11/sp1/krishnaveni.pdf), [2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-387-25465-X_40), [3](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1007733). What these articles essentially overview are methods to combat class imbalace (over/under-sampling, class weights, etc.) and metrics that can be used in these situations (ROC, g-mean, quadratic kappa, etc.)

Comment: could you take a look on the shared code i found a confusing results instead od improving performance of model using smote i got the contrast

Comment: From what I can tell judging by the confusion matrices, your first model (without balancing) predicts only the majority class, while the second one (with smote) predicts the other class. I would recommend maybe trying another classifier, as SVMs require a great deal of hyper-parameter tuning (i.e. running your model again and again in order to figure out the best C, gamma, kernel type, etc.).

Comment: thanks for you. i think changing the classifier is better because i use gridsearch tuning parameter and i trained both model on the best hyperparameters found by gridsearch algorithm